# Плавная прокрутка блоков новостей,

Tags: php, html, css, yii2

нужно сделать плавное прокручивание новостей вправо, 3 новости в ряд.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это организовать ?

```html
<section>
  <div class="box_news">
    <div id="gtco-main">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="row row-pb-md">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <ul id="gtco-post-list">
              <?php foreach ($countries as $country): ?>
              <li class="one-third entry animate-box" data-animate-effect="fadeIn">
                <figure>
                  <div class="entry-img" style="background-image: url(img/gallery-2.jpg"></div>
                </figure>
                <div class="entry-desc">
                  <h2 class="align-center top-title">
                    <p>
                      <?= $country->title ?>
                    </p>
                  </h2>
                  <div class="overflow-text-news">
                    <p1>
                      <p class="border-left-news">
                        <?= $country->text ?>
                      </p>
                    </p1>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box_bottom">
                  <?= Html::a('Читать далее',
                                            ['country/info', 'id' => $country->id]); ?>
                </div>
                <div class="box_bottom_date_posted">
                  <p><span class="date-posted">28.11.2018</span></p>
                </div>
              </li>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно смотреть в сторону **carousel**, например как тут - https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/carousel-product-cart-slider, и уже адаптировать под свои потребности.

Можно, конечно, изобретать велосипед, но зачем?